# Display text when hovering an image on a gallery using flexbox html/css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create an image gallery, and I want text to hover over the images using flexbox, but I am not sure how to achieve it. This is the code:

```css
.gallery-links-h2{
  font-family: Catamaran;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}


.gallery-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;

}


.gallery-image-1 {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  margin: 10px;
}


.gallery-image-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <main>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h2 class="gallery-links-h2"> Gallery </h2>
  </div>
  
  <section class="gallery-links">

        <a href="#" class="gallery-image-1">
          <img src="img/1.png">
        </a>

  </section>

 </main>
</body>
```

I want to add more images and make simple text appear when hovering the images, also i don't know how to add more images and apply the "flex configuration" to all of them and not just to only one. Would someone be so kind as to help me please Thank you everyone

Comment: https://www.developerdrive.com/responsive-image-gallery-flexbox/ refer this link.

Comment: There is no text in your code. And where is the text supposed to appear?

Comment: Thanks @AkhilAravind i'll check that. 
Paulie_D I know, i don't know where or how to insert it, i was thinking about creating a <div> with text inside the <a> tag but it didn't work. The idea is that when you hover over the image, text appears on top of the image, centered. My html knowledge is very basic i've been watching tutorials but there's a lot that i don't understand yet.